# Check with CSS what style is applied

Tags: css

I am looking for the next scenario in css where i will be able to check if a style is applied without using any javascript code.
 Example: If `flex: wrap` is applied add another style like `gap: 5`. All this computations should be done using only css. 
 I inspected the documentation but i did not find something similar. Could somebody help?

Comment: No, but you can have something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yxaqLfbm/), where you only apply the style if it's with another class.

Comment: You can’t select on a css property in the way you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the "gap" css. If there is a flex property used, only then the gap property will work. So no harm in using the gap property by default. Why check for whether flex is used or not.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand, to check a style is applied, it must use javascript code,
ex:

```
const box = document.getElementById('box');

//  Check if CSS property is contained in Style
if (box.style.backgroundColor) {
  console.log('value is', box.style.backgroundColor);
} else {
  console.log('CSS property is not contained in style');
}
```

Comment: He specifically stated he does not want to use javascript.